# Android: How generate sign APK only by Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, apk

Android Studio 2.3.3

My steps to generate **release** distributive (**sign APK** )

*Build->Generated Signed APK*

[image: Master pass]

[image: Generate sign apk step1]

[image: Generate sign apk step2]

Turn on: **V1 (Jar Signature)** and **V2 (Full APK Signature)**

And as result it generated sign apk: **app-release.apk**.

OK. It's work fine.

Now I want to do get same result only use Gradle (from console).
How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the official documentation at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-auto